# Boolean filter with checkbox on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-filters

I have an array of objects with property `published` which can be true or false.
I'm building a filter to be able to display only published or only not published items.

So far the published one works fine like this:

```
<input 
   type="checkbox" 
   ng-model="search.published" 
   ng-change="search.published = search.published ? true : undefined"> 
Published
```

And in the ng-repeat it looks like this:

```
ng-repeat="exhibitor in filterItems = (data | filter: search)"
```

The problem comes when I try to add another checkbox to display only unpublished items.

I've tried this with a second checkbox:

```
<input 
   type="checkbox" 
   ng-model="search.published" 
   ng-change="search.published = search.published ? false : undefined"> 
Unpublished
```

But of course it can't have the same model as the published items one. Also, the checkbox won't get ticked even if I remove the first checkbox.

Any tips on how to work around this?

Comment: I understand the question is about using checkboxes, but perhaps this could be converted into a UX question... does it make sense to use checkboxes like this? You could try using radio buttons or a select instead, it would save the hassle of workarounds and would be more intuitive

Comment: @PatrickBarr select was indeed the right way (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes automatically assign a true or false value to their `ng-model` values, so it is unnecessary to use `ng-change` the way you are.

```
<input 
   type="checkbox" 
   ng-model="search.published">
Published
```

When checked, `search.published` will be true. When unchecked, it will be false. 
Same goes for the second checkbox, but you should use a different `ng-model` property.

```
<input 
   type="checkbox" 
   ng-model="search.unpublished"> 
Unpublished
```

Next you will need to create a custom filter in your controller:

```
$scope.myCustomFilter = function(exhibitor) {
    if (exhibitor.published && exhibitor.published === $scope.search.published) {
        return exhibitor;
    } else if (!exhibitor.published && exhibitor.published === $scope.search.unpublished) {
        return exhibitor;
    }
};
```

You will need you make sure you define `$scope.search` in your controller.

```
$scope.search = {
    published: false,
    unpublished: false
};
```

Now for your `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-repeat="exhibitor in filterItems | filter:myCustomFilter"
```